# Async/Await: Reasoning and Implementation

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, async-await

so I started to learn Javascript and Python for Web Development. Now that I have a decent understanding of the basics I thought of trying something more advanced. After reading about Async/Await in both languages and Asynchronous Programming in general I wrote some simple examples just to get used to the syntax.

But now I face an issue. Even though I know how to use async/await I am really confused about why **await** only works inside of an **async** function. I read that this is just the way it is (because the languages define it in this way) and that async/await are just things that are converted to some other code construct to be executed. And this is where I got really confused. Because there has to be some sort of explanation that these two languages only allow it this way. Or am I missing something?

So my questions are: **Why does await only work inside of async?**

And: **How are they implemented in Python/Javascript?**

Every help/advise is greatly appreciated. :)

If I wrote this Post in a wrong way or so please let me know so that I can fix it. Keep in mind I am really new to this.

Best regards
Nico

Comment: `How are they implemented in Python/Javascript?` - Python is open source, you can review the implementation online - https://www.python.org/.  `Why does await only work inside of async?` - when you design something you have to decide how it will work and what kind of *interface* it will have; simple answer is those are the choices the designers made. I did read somewhere that the *async/await* paradigm/syntax existed in other languages before Python's implementation and that was a design consideration.

Comment: First of all thank u very much for replying. :) Mhm, so do I understand it correctly that because of the design that was chosen and because async functions are "special" functions (like iterators/generators which they are based on) that can start and stop their own execution, await is just a another way of saying stop here, give another part of the program time to do their thing and wait for a return value? And because waiting isnt possible inside of a normal function it can only work inside of async?

Comment: And I know that Python is open source but I only worked with Python itself and not C so I can only guess what the code does. :(

Comment: This question seems off-topic to me. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.